# How to get WKT from a QgsGeometry object?

Tags: qgis, python, geometry, well-known-text

How can I get the wkt from a geometry object in python?
I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feat.geometry()
    #print something meaningful about the geom object
```

I've checked `dir(geom)`, but there doesn't seem to be an option to get a wkt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WKt can be obtained from geom as follows:
`your_string = geom.exportToWkt()`

Answer (score 10):

In QGIS 3 there was a [backwards incompatible change](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) about this:

> exportToWkt() was renamed to asWkt()

So now it is: `your_string = geom.asWkt()`